# Scala interpreter says object is not a member of package, when it is

Tags: scala

I forgot to compile a Scala object required by a Scala script. But after compiling that object, the scala interpreter still complained that the object was not a member of the package!

Comment: Not enough information _by far_. How did you specify the classpath? In which directory did you run REPL? Did you exit REPL after compiling the object? Did you start REPL on a new directory? In other words, we really need to know the exact steps that were taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your classpath is correct...

This is caused by a bug in the scalac compile server. You need to kill all processes (there may be more than one) with command lines that end with `scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer`.